# Set DataFormatString in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a GridView with some columns and i need change DataFormatString from code behind, because i need set different values for different regions.

This is my column with date, which i need format from code behind. If i set DataFormatString here, so it is ok.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="LastChange" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gwHeader"
ItemStyle-CssClass="gwItem center"HeaderText="Last change"
DataFormatString="{0:dd.MM.yyyy}"> </asp:BoundField>
```

But if i try it change in code behind it doesn't work (original date from database was not formatted by pattern in DataFormatString)

I tried:

```
BoundField lastChange = GridView1.Columns[11] as BoundField;
lastChange.DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}";
```

I put it into Page_Load and GridView1_RowDataBound

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by _it doesn't work_ exactly? You get any error or exception? Unexpected result?

Comment: When i change it in aspx so it change format, but when i change it in code behind, the original format is same, but if i set other format.

Comment: Have you tried removing the DataFormatString property first from your .aspx then declare it using code-behind?

Comment: Yes, but i know where is the problem, someone before me save datetime as varchar in db and that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**You could set it from codebehind using below code:**

```
public static string myFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}";

((BoundField)GridView1.Columns[ColumnIndex]).DataFormatString = myFormatString;
```